# Wordpress change menu from opening on hover to click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a site http://themerkle.com and I have been trying to change the stick hamburger menu on the top left from opening up on hover to opening up when someone click it. Reason being, on a smartphone the menu stays open because hover is not meant to support touchscreen devices.

I tried looking for the css part which enables the hovering but even after disabling most of the css lines for the top-menu like

```
#top-menu-selector:hover{color:#BD2A33;-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 12);box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);}
    #top-menu ul li:hover ul, 
    #top-menu ul li:hover ul li a,
```

the menu still appears to open on mouse hover. I also tried disabling javascript but the menu still opens. I narrowed it down to the following function which actually creates the menu in sticky.php:

```
<?php //title attribute gets in the way - remove it
$menu = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top-menu', 'container' => false, 'fallback_cb' => 'fallback_pages', 'echo' => false ) );
$menu = preg_replace('/title=\"(.*?)\"/','',$menu);
echo $menu;
?>
```

I am not sure where i can change the css or add the required js to the menu to open on mouse click, any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

After further investigating I found that by removing the below element the menu stops expanding on hover.

```
<ul class="sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">
```

Now I need to figure out how to enable expansion on click.

UPDATE 2:

Fixed by adding an onclick function to the top menu as such:

```
<div id="top-menu" onclick="show_hide_menu();">
```

Then adding the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicked = false;
function show_hide_menu()
{
    if(clicked == false){
        document.getElementById("menu-main").style.display = "none";
        clicked = true;
    }else if (clicked == true){
        document.getElementById("menu-main").style.display = "block";
        clicked = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

The solution does not require messing with the hover implementation and simply adds an option to close the menu when you click it. It seems to also override the hover event which is good.

Comment: You have to add the onclick function where hover is fired and call the function their.....

Comment: My issue is i can't find where the hover is firing. the ul element with the class sf-js-enabled is defined without a class in the php file. So somewhere the class for that particular ul is being set and i can't find where

Comment: hover is firing on the menu image..

Comment: when you hover the menu image their will be new class added on li element and display:none for ul element you just override these two...

Comment: it is firing in to thescript with path your template direcory/steam/js/plugins.min.js on mouse out or mouse over event...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('#top-menu .menu-item-has-children > a').removeAttr('href');
$('#top-menu .menu-item-has-children').click(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').css({'display':'block','visibility':'visible'});
});
</script>
```

try this and let me know if it works... this is not a really good one, but might be functional

Comment: That was close enough, posted solution in OP. Thanks!